# Callback URL Twitter API not functioning and authorizing

Tags: python, twitter, callback, tweepy, twitter-oauth

Hey guys I am trying to build this twitter bot, I am using the library tweepy. I turned on OAuth 1.0a turned on to get read and write access but I am unable to authorize the app.
I am not able to get the pin value which I can use in auth.get_access_token(verifier=None)

My code :

```
import tweepy
import webbrowser
import time
consumer_key = "value"
consumer_secret = "value"

access_token = "value"
access_token_secret = "value"
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,access_token_secret  )
redirect_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
print(redirect_url)
webbrowser.open(redirect_url) #stuck here as when I click authorize the app it redirects to the callback url which says "Directory listing for /?oauth_token="value"&oauth_verifier="value"
user_pint_input = input("What's the pin value?")
```

I have put `local host 8080` as the callback url which I started through `python3 -m http.server --cgi 8080`

I am unsure about this callback url due to lack of info on this. I am doing it wrong. How can I rectify it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Tweepy documentation [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/authentication.html#pin-based-oauth):

> The PIN-based OAuth flow can be used by setting the callback parameter to "oob":

```py
import tweepy

oauth1_user_handler = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    "API / Consumer Key here", "API / Consumer Secret here",
    callback="oob"
)
```

There is no question of callback if you use this authentication method.

Comment: yes I did exactly this but it still redirects. Inorder to get read and write access you would need to allow oauth1a turned on where you add callback url and the url redirects to that. What you saying is only for when we doing only read I guess. Am I wrong ?

Comment: is there a way to allow read and write in settings without Oauth1a and Oauth2a?

Comment: @kavyabhargava I think that you are mixing up three different choices: 1. Callback authorization or pin-based authorization (mainly an ergonomic choice) ; 2. Oauth1.0a or Oauth2 authentication (acting in the behalf of some user or in the behalf of your app) ; 3. Read or Read&write permissions (depends only of your choice in the developper portal). Those three choices are distincts (except that an app will not be able to use any write permissions, obviously).